# Is SSHFS or FTP better

Tags: server, file-sharing

I have SSH enabled on my Ubuntu Server so that I can remotely manage and configure it. I want to make it a file server so that people on my LAN can upload files onto it or download files. Should I use FTP to do so, or should I avoid opening another port by just using SSHFS? Another way to word this is, what are the benefits of FTP over SSHFS?

Comment: It depends, both have advantages and disadvantages. Can you describe what you are using it for ? file transfer? one way, two way ? Over the internet ? Over a LAN ? How important is security ?

Comment: File transfer, two way. Probably over a LAN, maybe over the internet in the near future. Security isn't too crucial.

Comment: If security is not crucial and you are on a LAN, FTP is fine. Alternates include samba. Over the internet ssh (sshfs) or kerberos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, go with SSHFS.  All you need to do is set up a guest account and password that can be SSH'd into.  Then users can upload anything they want into a folder on the server.  FTP is much less secure, and is easier to hack/be hacked.  I would go with SSHFS.  Plus, you get the added benefit of being able to use RSA/DSA authentication keys.

Comment: Thanks! But what exactly are RSA/DSA authentication keys?

Comment: This should help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: And if you like this answer, please mark it as accepted with the little check mark to the left.